# How can I connect the two parts of a Socket in c++ for Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, visual-studio-2012, hyperlink

I'm working on a Project in c++ that use Sockets to get data from a server and work with it.
I have a problem with that, because when i receive a very long message from the server, my Project can't read it because it is divided in two parts and i never received it or just the last part.
Can someone help me to solve this?
Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <WinSock2.h> //Esta puta da problemas, mejor usar #include <Windows.h>
#include <queue>
#include <mutex>
#include <regex>
#include <process.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

//Datos de la Socket
int st = 1000;
int sendCTR = 10000;

void main() {

        //start sockets
        WSADATA wsaData;
        if (::WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) && wsaData.wVersion != MAKEWORD(2, 2)) {
                std::cout
                        << "Cannot start up socket library: " << ::WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
                std::getchar();
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

        }


        sockaddr_in gameAddr;
        gameAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        gameAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr(NT_GAME_SERVER_IP);
        gameAddr.sin_port = htons(NT_GAME_SERVER_PORT);
        gameSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (connect(gameSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&gameAddr, sizeof(gameAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                std::cout
                        << "Cannot connect to GameServer (" << NT_GAME_SERVER_IP << ":" << NT_GAME_SERVER_PORT << "), retrying..." << std::endl;
                goto GAME;
        }

        Send(gameSocket, std::to_string(Session));
        Sleep(500);
        Send(gameSocket, NT_USER, Session);
        Sleep(300);
        Send(gameSocket, NT_PSSW, Session);
        long long lastPulse = time(NULL), pulseCounter = 0;
        Sleep(300);

        //log packets
        std::vector<unsigned char> gameBuffer(0x4000);
        int gameRecvLen;
        ses = Session;
        std::thread t(Order);
        while ((gameRecvLen = recv(gameSocket, (char*)&gameBuffer.front(), gameBuffer.size(), NULL)) > 0 && gameRecvLen < 0x4000) {
                for each(std::string gamePacket in decryptit(gameBuffer, gameRecvLen)) {
                        if (gamePacket == "") continue; //Null stuff...
                        std::vector<std::string> Packet = Crypto::split(gamePacket, ' ');
                        //MAIN STUFF

                }
        }


}
```

Comment: If you are using TCP, you should be aware that it can only transfer 'messages' of one byte.  Anything longer needs a protocol on top of TCP.

Comment: TCP/UDP?, protocol?, code? Can you change the server or only the client?

Comment: I use TCP, Now I'll add part of the code.

Comment: What happens if recv() returns with 1, ie. only one byte is received?

Comment: I don't know what you mean

Comment: It is valid for recv() to return having only read one byte.  decryptit() will then be called with only one byte.  Presumably, it will return no strings, having failed, and recv() will be called again on the continue, reading more data at gameBuffer.front.  Fine, except that decryptit() is called with gameRecvLen - the number of bytes received on the LAST call to recv - not the sum of all bytes received.

Comment: Actually... This is my problema, Is there any way to do that?